# Get branch and bound node count in JuMP/Gurobi

Tags: julia, gurobi, julia-jump

I am trying to get the branch and bound node count using the JuMP interface and the Gurobi solver in Julia.

I tried getnodecount(m) as suggested on the JuMP website, but this came back as undefined. After doing more research, I read to try:
`MathProgBase.getnodecount(m)`

A simple example:

```
using Gurobi
using JuMP
using MathProgBase

m = Model(with_optimizer(Gurobi.Optimizer))
@variable(m, x, Bin)
@variable(m, y >=0)
@objective(m, Min, x*y)

optimize!(m)
println(value(x))

# getnodecount(m)
MathProgBase.getnodecount(m)
```

I expected to get a node count of 0, but got this error:

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching getnodecount(::Model)
```

`Closest candidates are:`
`getnodecount(!Matched::Gurobi.GurobiMathProgModel) at` `/uliapro/JuliaPro_v1.1.1.1/packages/Gurobi/dlJep/src/MPB_wrapper.jl:759`

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using the new `MathOptInterface` rather than `MathProgBase`. That is why you do not get a `GurobiMathProgModel` and hence the error. In `MathOptInterface`, you can do the following to get the node count.

```
MOI.get(model, MOI.NodeCount())
```

which will call the `Gurobi.get_node_count(model::Model)` method implemented [here](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/Gurobi.jl/blob/2ba66a47a19050cca16f719eb1735a5620bb535a/src/grb_solve.jl#L74). For other attributes, please refer to [the MOI API Reference.](http://www.juliaopt.org/MathOptInterface.jl/stable/apireference/#API-Reference-1)